# Is it possible to set the name of dynamic ports?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Is there some way to set the name of dynamic ports? 
e.g. trying the SendMail SDK sample and I've got a send port with the name ...

> SendMail_1.0.0.0_Microsoft.Samples.BizTalk.SendMail.ReceiveSend_DynamicSendPort_2718f63506c1b197

Or if not set it, at least some way to control the naming convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the name in BizTalk administrator, but it will get overwritten each time you Deploy.

No, there is no way to influence the auto-named Ports.

Comment: Thanks again for the BizTalk knowledge ... blast, I'd hoped I'd just missed something  :-(

Comment: I know, it's very messy looking.  One of the reasons I avoid Dynamic Ports whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an automated process for deployment, somtheng like the deployment framework for biztalk, you can add some extra work with powershell to delete auto generated dynamic port and recreate it with the good name.